# LINQ group by date descending, and order by time ascending

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have the following model:

```
public class A
{
  public int? Id {get;set;}
  public DateTime Start {get;set;}
  public DateTime End {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to group all the entries by date, and sort them per date descending, and sorting per time ascending (using LINQ). Example output:

```
Jan 3. 2012
-- 10:00-11:00
-- 11:00-13:00
Jan 2. 2012
-- 10:00-11:00
-- 12:00-15:00
Jan 1. 2012
-- 9:00-10:00
-- 12:00-13:00
```

Is it possible to achieve this in LINQ-to-SQL or do I have to this after the query has executed (on the result list)?

Comment: `Start` and `End` are just DateTime entries, e.g. to visualize a timetable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
IEnumerable<A> sorted = listOfA.OrderByDescending(a => a.Start.Date)
                               .ThenBy(a => a.Start.TimeOfDay);
```

Comment: Thanks, but got the following error: `The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.` So I put your code after the query has executed and it works fine :)